# Best Embedded SQL DB for write performance?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, firebird, embedded-database

Has anybody done any benchmarking/evaluation of the popular open-source embedded SQL DBs for performance, particularly write performance?  I've some 1:1 comparisons for sqlite, Firebird Embedded, Derby and HSQLDB (others I am missing?) but no across the board comparisons... Also, I'd be interested in the overall developer experience for any of these (for a Java app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [benchmark from db4o](http://hsqldb.org/PolePosition.pdf) might be helpful. It includes, JavaDB (Built on top of Derby), HSQLDB, SqlLite.

It seems HSQLDB out-performs its counterparts, especially when writing is concerned. H2, as a successor of HSQLDB, is faster than HSQLDB in both read and write with optimizing, clustering, transaction isolation features.

Comment: Err, HSQLDB is the SLOWEST. You've read the graphs incorrectly (lower is better in this case).

Comment: Marchaos: My dear, marchaos. Is it not possible that they have modified the graph? After all, it has been 4 years since I provided the link here. Nonetheless, I need to edit the post. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The link was to the PolePosition benchmark version 0.4 with the older HSQLDB 1.8.0. The results of this benchmark with more recent versions of databases is here: http://hsqldb.org/PolePosition.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Check out the comparison on the [H2 Site](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html).

I'm using it for [my Eclipse plugin](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/) and I'm very happy with it. Extremely fast for embedded use, very easy to use (one single JAR), great community support, highly recommended.