# Java application with own database

Tags: java, database, netbeans

I want to develop using java and netbeans 8.0 an application that stores/edit/removes data form into a own database contained at application, not using a remote database. There is any suggestion to create that "onboard" database?

Comment: What's the complexity and performance requirements? Will it be a one-user desktop application or a search engine servicing billions of users?

Comment: You can use sqlite for serverless application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to an embedded database for a simple desktop command or command line application, these options can store  data in memory or in a file:

- HSQL http://hsqldb.org/
- Derby http://db.apache.org/derby/
- SqlLite https://www.sqlite.org/

This is old but could be a reference [Best Embedded SQL DB for write performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539288/best-embedded-sql-db-for-write-performance)